# Complete Button Functionality Change

Tags: java, erp, adempiere

I am trying to add some code in the completeit() method of MInOut.java. I am maintaining patches of code and this new functionality will be a Patch altogether.

Now my problem is if I add MinOut.java in my patch it will override the base class MinOut.java and if someone changes base MinOut.java the changes won't be reflected in Build as patch will overwrite the code.

> Can Anyone guide a method with which I can achieve this i.e modifying of CompleteIt functionality without the fear that future changes to base class wont be reflected...

Comment: Is there some eventing mechanism triggering the `completeit()` call in the first place?

Comment: yes in the system there is a button Complete which triggers completeit()

Comment: What is the eventing technology? Are you using javascript to servlet via ajax, wicket? Please elaborate.

Comment: The other question is: why can't you modify the original code? I don't understand the requirement of delivering a different library.

Comment: The main idea , of not modifying original code is that if in future someone using the erp does not want to use a particular module , he may just delete the jar file of patch and functionality will be gone and original code will be left altogether.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve base class as it is, you should use ModelValidator (instead of Model class which will override your base class) to hook your business logic before/after complete document event. Refer for more info: http://wiki.adempiere.net/ModelValidator